# No provider found for RadioControlRegistry with simple component

Tags: angular, angular-dart

I have simple Angular-Dart component, trying connect property to `ngModel` in radio input, app compiling correctly, but browser console gives me error:

```
No provider found for RadioControlRegistry: RadioControlValueAccessor -> RadioControlRegistry.
```

the code:

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_forms/angular_forms.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'order-question-test',
  template: '''
    <input type="radio" name="food" [(ngModel)]="foodChicken">
    <input type="radio" name="food" [(ngModel)]="foodFish">
       ''',
  directives: [
    coreDirectives,
    formDirectives,
  ]
)

class OrderQuestion {
  RadioButtonState foodChicken = RadioButtonState(true, "chicken");
   RadioButtonState foodFish = RadioButtonState(false, "fish");
  OrderQuestion ();
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.2.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  angular: ^5.2.0
  angular_components: ^0.13.0
  json_annotation: ^2.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  angular_test: ^2.2.0
  build_runner: ^1.5.0
  build_test: ^0.10.3
  build_web_compilers: ^1.0.0
  json_serializable: ^2.0.0
  pedantic: ^1.0.0
  test: ^1.5.1
```

whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **`RadioControlRegistry`** under [providers](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/issues/1832) array

```
 providers: [ClassProvider(RadioControlRegistry)]
```

Comment: No dice, get `Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions`, and there's a syntax error in the linked github response (no `,` after `directives`). I think it might actually be `providers: [FORM_PROVIDERS]`

Answer (score 0):

You need `providers: [FORM_PROVIDERS]` in your component

```
@Component(
  selector: 'order-question-test',
  template: '''
    <input type="radio" name="food" [(ngModel)]="foodChicken">
    <input type="radio" name="food" [(ngModel)]="foodFish">
       ''',
  directives: [
    coreDirectives,
    formDirectives,
  ],
  providers: [FORM_PROVIDERS]  // added
)

class OrderQuestion {
  // ...
}
```